# How to display multiple images in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, activeadmin

I am using paperclip to upload multiple images. I am also using Active Admin. So far, I have been able to upload multiple images and associate them to my 'product' model. I am also able to display the **"names"** of all the associated images in the index page . However , I am unable to find out how to ***display*** 'all' the images (not just names) in my show page of the product model. Please find the code below.

\app\models\product.rb

```
has_many :images, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, :allow_destroy => true
```

\app\models\image.rb

```
belongs_to :product
has_attached_file :image, :styles => {
  :thumb=> "100x100>",
  :small  => "300x300>",
  :large => "600x600>"
    }
```

\app\admin\products.rb

```
index do
  column "Images" do |product|
    product.images.map(&:image_file_name).join("<br />").html_safe
  end
end

show do |product|
  attributes_table do
  row "Images" do
      ul do
        li do 
          image_tag(product.images.first.image.url(:small))
        end
        li do 
          image_tag(product.images.second.image.url(:small))
        end
        li do 
          image_tag(product.images.last.image.url(:small))
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I have found something that works but this is really bad programming. I have currently 3 images associated to each product and I am using the above code inside my show block .
Please suggest a better way to do this.

Comment: I have modified the code to display the image only if it is present. `image_tag(product.images.first.image.url(:small)) if !product.images.first.nil?` However, this code still has a limitation of max. 3 images. Please advice on how to achieve this in a better way.

Comment: do you mean you need to display each image not just 3 of them ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

do you mean you need to display each one image not just 3 of them ? If yes try to

```
row "Images" do
   ul do
    product.images.each do |img|
      li do 
        image_tag(img.image.url(:small))
      end
    end
   end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ... This works . However , is there a way where I can display the first image as :small and the rest as :thumb ?